# IOS swift implement Android fragment transaction

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, android-fragments, uikit

I and a new developer just transfer from Android to Ios swift. Right now I am developing a application and I have implement the android version but I could not find the similar solution in IOS.

Let's say I have a viewpicker with 100 options on the top of screen, and for each selection I want to display different layout. For example, I choose option1 then below the viewpicker there are 3 labels and textfield displayed, if I choose option2, there are three viewpickers and three buttons displayed.

In Android, I could use fragment transaction to implement this, but I don't see any similar solution in IOS right now. Any solution to solve it?

Comment: Do you want to show the respective view after selection on same activity/fragment or new one ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent to Android's fragments in Cocoa-Touch. You manipulate `UIView` objects with `UIViewControllers`. To get the sort of master-detail behavior you're after, try looking into [`UISplitViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/).